# Using websocket/socket.io for partial page refresh

Tags: socket.io

Installed websocket and socket.io to run an IM in my website and to do partial page refreshes.   The IM is coded and working fine.
To do partial page refreshes, I coded this in the server:

```
// receive and broadcast log or monitors update
   socket.on('sendUpdate', function(ID)
   {
      io.sockets.emit('getUpdate', ID);
   });
```

and this in the client:

```
// send update log or monitors to the server
    function sendUpdate(ID)  // for log and monitors table changes
    {
      socket.emit('sendUpdate', ID); // send it to the server for broadcast to all clients
    };

    // receive log or monitors update
    function getUpdate(ID)
    {
  // how to do this???
};
```

So, how can I update the html element by id without refreshing the whole page?
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Refresh with what? You mean re-load from server only that html element? Don't think that's possible. However if you send/receive **the data** that you want displayed/refreshed with you can update the element with that data: `$('#'+ID).html('whatever you want to update it with');` Is this what you want?

Comment: use `socket.on('getUpdate', function(data) {...});`